# Drawing paths from a point where each path is distanced from the initial point

Tags: java, android, canvas, path, point

I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to draw paths from a point  on a canvas with the start of each path being equally distanced from the initial point. To illustrate what I mean, the code that I have so far is able to generate this:[image]

and the desired result is something like this:

[image]

My code:

```
int n = 3;
int r;
double x;
double y;
point1 = new Point(mWidth/2, mHeight/2);
double angle;
double angleFactor;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        angleFactor = 2 * Math.PI / n;
        angle = i * angleFactor;
        x = (point1.x) + r * Math.cos(angle);
        y = (point1.y) + r * Math.sin(angle);

        //Draw paths
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
        path.lineTo((float) x, (float) y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

}
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have a tiny distance between the offset of a line and the center point, you can define start coordinates like this:

```
double xStart, xEnd;
double yStart, yEnd;
double offsetFraction = 0.1;
```

Inside the `for` loop in `onDraw()` :

```
double lengthX = r * Math.cos(angle);
double lengthY = r * Math.sin(angle);

xStart = (point1.x) + offsetFraction * lengthX;
yStart = (point1.y) + offsetFraction * lengthY;
xEnd = (point1.x) + lengthX;
yEnd = (point1.y) + lengthY;

//Draw paths
path.reset();
path.moveTo((float) xStart, (float) yStart);
path.lineTo((float) xEnd, (float) yEnd);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was after thank you!